# Database: mark entity (record) as deleted for certain users

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational-database

Given a database table with records that multiple users in an application can see, what is the most efficient way to mark a record deleted for multiple users without actually deleting the record itself (soft delete)?

#### Requirements:

- Multiple users should be able to mark the record as deleted
- When user A marks the record as deleted, user B, C, D... should still be able to see it until they mark it as deleted themselves
- An administrative user should be able to mark the record as deleted so that the record is no longer visible for others.

I've thought about the following example but I am curious to see what other programmers would do.

#### Table: entity

```
+----------------+---------------+--------+
| id             | data          | active |
| (int, primary) | (varchar)     | (int)  |
+----------------+---------------+--------+
|              1 | foo           |      1 | <-- this record is active (visible)
|              2 | bar           |      0 | <-- no user can see this record
+----------------+---------------+--------+
```

An administrative user could set the `active` flag to 0 to effectively remove the record from the scope of all users.

#### Table: entity_deleted_user

```
+----------------+----------------+
| entity_id      | user_id        | 
| (int, primary) | (int, primary) |
+----------------+----------------+
|              1 |            100 | <--
|              1 |            150 | <-- Users 100, 150 and 37 can not see entity 1
|              1 |             37 | <--
+----------------+----------------+
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

What you've described is how to do it in a relational manner. Effectively it's a one-to-many mapping: you are attempting to map the state of one item (the entity) to many (the users). The ability of the admin to override the status only applies to the entity, so it should be in the entity table.

An alternative -and non-relational- method could be to use a single integer field as a bit set in the entity table, with each bit representing the deleted entity status of an individual user. This would remove the need for the entity_deleted_user table (and the admin could simply set all the bits to hide it from everyone) but this scheme has many disadvantages (limited user count, no referential integrity, etc).

Comment: Even with the limited user count and lack of referential integrity this is a valuable option for smaller applications. Thank you.